# Lexmark S305 and Ubuntu 12.10 : no usb recognition

Tags: lexmark

I am having trouble setting my new Dell v313w printer (which is a Lexmark S305 with a Dell logo) on Ubuntu 12.10.

I installed the drivers from http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=product&segment=DOWNLOAD&productCode=LEXMARK_IMPACT_S305&locale=en&userlocale=DE#2 they only have drivers for Ubuntu 12.04 but that should not be a problem, or should it?

After that Ubuntu sees that I have a Lexmark printer and propose me to plug it in via usb in order to configure it.

But it does not see the printer although it is connected to my computer via usb.

This printer does not have an ethernet port so I can only access it via usb.

What should I do?

Thanks for your replies.

Regards.

Comment: have you tried any alternate USB cable?

Comment: I haven't any other, so I will have to get a new one somewhere (but not today) in order to try that. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It's a usb-A to usb-B type of cable, hard to get :)

Comment: Just for your information.... I see your printer Dell v313w even has wireless support, so have you tried connecting wireless?

Comment: How do I do that? Don't I need to do it via my computer?

Comment: Don't you have the manual for your printer? you need it for sure to make it work.

Comment: Ok, I was able to access it but it seems that the drivers are not working, because after a test print I had the following error : error during the CUPS operation: 'client-error-document-format-not-supported'.